# Virtual Assistant Bot Framework and Control library

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework, microsoft-teams, control-library

I'm developing a Virtual Assistant in order to being published in Microsoft Teams, what I find out is that using the adaptive cards there are some limitation in Teams because of the version (for example the buttons need to be always at the end of the card). I would like to have a better UX and I find out that Teams supports the Control Library in React (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/app-studio-component-library).

Now my question is if also the Virtual Assistant is able to support something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Teams Control Library is intended for developers creating web pages for things like [Tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-overview) and [Task Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/task-modules/task-modules-overview) in Teams so that the styling matches the rest of the app without much additional work. Unfortunately, there is not a way to use this package directly in the chat window for things like cards.

If you are trying to customize the button placement in an Adaptive Card, I've seen some developers add an [image](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Image.html) of a button to the card and then set the `selectAction` property of the image to create a sudo button. Not exactly ideal, but it might work for your scenario.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Quick question @tdurnford, officially Teams only supports v1.0 of the adaptive cards https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/cards/cards-reference#adaptive-card , but `selectAction` is only available in v1.1 https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Image.html, and I have tested it in Teams and it works. Is this just a one-off thing, or does Teams actually support the full 1.1 schema?

Comment: I believe that’s just a one off thing. As far as I know, Teams only supports Adaptive Cards v1.0

Comment: @tdurnford Thanks for the answer, yes the images is actually the way we are working around the version limitation.